# Making Cmakelist (ros) failure

Tags: cmake, ros, catkin

After installing ros(melodic version), I followed the below steps one by one.

```
$ mkdir -p catkin_ws/src
$ cd catkin_ws/src
$ catkin_init_workspace
$ cd ..
$ catkin_make
```

Then error came up like this

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:1:
  Parse error.  Expected a command name, got unquoted argument with text
  "/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/hangilkim/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/hangilkim/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Makefile:320: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I found that CMakeLists.txt file in 'home/catkin_ws/src' folder exists clearly, but contain only this message.

```
/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake
```

How can I solve this problem??

Comment: does `/opt/ros/melodic/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake` exist?

Comment: Have you sourced the ROS env with `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to compile an already compiled project. So delete the CMakeLists.txt file in 'home/catkin_ws/src' or for safety measures move it to another folder then run catkin_make command on your terminal.